# jQuery tools: How to close an overlay?

Tags: jquery-tools

I have an edit form that I'm displaying as an overlay using Jquery Tools.

On my object list view page, each object has `<a href="#" class="edit_button">Edit</a>`. All of these are attached to the same overlay form with:

```
        $(".edit_button[rel]").overlay({ top: '5px',
            fixed: false,

            mask: {
                color: '#ebecff',
                loadSpeed: 200,
                opacity: 0.9
            }
        });
```

The edit form overlay contains a cancel button:

```
<a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
```

How can I make this cancel button close the overlay? It seems that the only way I can get access to the Overlay API object is to use the selector that created it - in this case `$('.edit').each()` since I don't know which one triggered the overlay.

What I really want to do is something like:

```
$('.cancel').click(function(e){
    var target = e.originalTarget || e.srcElement;
    $(target).parent().parent().getOverlay().close();
});
```

but this doesn't work.

Is there any way I can close the overlay without doing:

```
$(".edit_button[rel]").each(function() {
    $(this).overlay().close();
});
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can easily add more closing
>   elements inside the overlay simply by
>   assigning the CSS class name "close"
>   to them. These elements can be styled
>   and positioned any way you like inside
>   the overlay.
>
> If you supply a value for the close
>   configuration variable, the close
>   element is not auto-generated and you
>   need to define the closing element(s)
>   yourself.

So if you put `<a href="#" class="cancel close">Cancel</a>` it should work.

Comment: what do you do if this content is loaded in through ajax. i have html being loaded into the overlay and in that html there is a button to close. I put a class of close and it does not work. ANy thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To close the modal with JavaScript (automatically without clicking the close button):

```
$('#ID OF YOUR MODAL a.close').trigger("click");
```

or if you are in an iframe (like me), put parent. before the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Kras provided. If you only have one Overlay open at once (which logically you will do) then you can use this more generic approach perhaps:

```
  $('a.close').trigger('click');
```

I hope this helps!